# Missing line of data using Getline with Ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

Ok so this is killing me at the moment cause its such a simple part of my program that just doesn't want to work. I'm reading data from a textfile to use in a GA.

The first getline() works perfectly, but the second one doesn't want to write any data into my string. When i cout the string it doesn't show anything.

Here is the code:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fname.c_str());
char pop[20], mut[20];

inFile.getline(pop,20);
cout << pop;
inFile.getline(mut,20);
cout << mut; //this outputs nothing
```

Thanks for any help in advance.
A sample form my file:
there is no line between them mutation is the line straight after population

Population size: 30
Mutation: 20

Comment: Just a hint: factor the `ifstream` out into a function accepting an `istream`, and write a unit test for it with a `stringstream` containing "a\nb".

Comment: By the way, could you enlighten us with a peek at the first two lines of your input file?

Answer (score 3):

Your file's first line is 20 characters long (19+new line) but `pop[20]` can only contain 19 (because the last one is reserved for the null terminator '\0').

When [`istream::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) stops because it has extracted 20-1 characters, it doesn't discard the new line delimiter (because it was never read). So the next `getline` just reads the end of the **first** line, discarding the new line.

That's why you get nothing in the second string.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the length of your input line exceeds the length of the buffer which must hold it.

The solution is to not use character arrays. This is C++, use `std::string`!

```
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fname.c_str());

std::string pop;
std::getline(inFile, pop);
cout << pop << "\n";

std::string mut;
std::getline(inFile, mut);
cout << mut << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to find out what the problem is.  Add error checking code to your `getline` calls, refactor the (simple) code into a (simple) function, with a (simple) unittest.  Possibly, your second line is longer than the assumed 20 characters (null-term included!).

For an idea of what I mean, take a look at [this snippet](http://codepad.org/tiRdtlFH).

Comment: I have done many unit tests to test every simple thing I could think of. I use a char array now because getline(inFile, line); doesnt work where line is a string, it just outputs nothing

Comment: Well the snippet you show us, when put into a function, works nicely. I added your input to my test - so possibly one of your input lines is longer than you thinkk.

Comment: yes thanks I should just have changed getline to take 21 characters, +1. It's a shame though I can't get getline(inFile, line); to work

Comment: @user1763722 What the problem with `getline(inFile, line);`? That is the best way to do it, you should be asking about that, instead of trying inferior methods.

Comment: it just doesn't put anything inside of 'line'. Any string i use with that version of getline is blank

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
while (getline(in,line,'\n')){
    //do something with line
}
```

or try something like

```
string text;
string temp; 
ifstream file;
  file.open ("test_text.txt");

  while (!file.eof())
  {
    getline (file, temp);
    text.append (temp); // Added this line
  }
```

Comment: ok i tried that code but it doesn't put any string inside temp, is there something wrong with my compiler? because a plain getline(file, line); doesn't work at all

Comment: Please don't recommend using `.eof()` as a loop condition. It [almost always produces buggy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), as it has in this case.